One variable binomial inequality
I have a proof for the following inequality:

$$ \sum_{j = 0}^{8}\binom{8}{j}\left(j + 5\right)!\,\left(8 -
j\right)!\,x^{j} \geq 13!\,\left(x^{2} + \frac{1}{6}\right)^{4}, $$
for all $x\geq 0$.


To describe what I did, expand everything and collect terms in the left hand side.
Then use the AM-GM inequality for the terms $x^{3}$ and $x$, $x^{5}$ and $x^{3}$ and $x^{7}$ and $x^{5}$.
What is important is that twice the minimum of each of the above coefficients is at least the coefficient of the intermediate even power.
However, I feel that this approach is not general and not nice.

Could you please provide an alternative one?.

What is $8->j$?

It is $8-j$. Corrected, thanks.

Taking the difference, you get a 7 degree polynomial, which has a real root at $ x \approx -0.0011$. So, were you wanting $ x > 0$, esp in order to apply AM-GM?

@Calvin Lin I used the AM-GM for the odd powers, which should be positive.

@CalvinLin In my initial post $x\geq 0$ was there, but someone changed it and it disappeared. Sorry for this.

Thanks for adding that in. $\quad$ FWIW Looking at the edits, you didn't mention $ x \geq 0 $ previously.

@CalvinLin Then it seems that I would like to write and never written. Sorry about it.

Your idea looks nice to me.
I'm going to write another idea though my idea may not be very nice.
Our inequality is equivalent to
$$f(x):=114048 x^7 - 57024 x^6 + 36288x^5-12744x^4 + 8064 x^3 - 408 x^2 + 864 x + 1\ge 0$$
We can write
$$f(x)\gt 114048 x^7  + 57024x^5\bigg(\frac 12- x\bigg)+ 12744x^3\bigg(\frac 12-x\bigg)  + 408x\bigg(\frac 12- x\bigg)  + 1$$
So, we can say that for $0\le x\lt\frac 12$, $f(x)\ge 0$ holds.
We can also write
$$f(x)\gt 114048 x^6\bigg(x-\frac 12\bigg) + 36288x^4 \bigg(x-\frac 12\bigg) + 8064x^2\bigg(x-\frac 12\bigg)+ 864 x + 1$$
So, we can say that for $x\ge\frac 12$, $f(x)\ge 0$ holds.$\ \blacksquare$
The above idea can be written as follows :
If $a_i\gt 0\ (0\le i\le 7)$ and
$$\max\bigg(\frac{a_2}{a_3},\frac{a_4}{a_5},\frac{a_6}{a_7}\bigg)\le\min\bigg(\frac{a_1}{a_2},\frac{a_3}{a_4},\frac{a_5}{a_6}\bigg)$$ then $$a_7x^7 - a_6 x^6 + a_5x^5-a_4x^4 + a_3x^3 - a_2 x^2 + a_1x + a_0\ge 0$$ for all $x\ge 0$.

In the following, I'm going to write what I've observed which may interest you.
We can prove in a similar way that the following stronger inequality holds :
$$ \sum_{j = 0}^{8}\binom{8}{j}(j + 5)!(8 -
j)!\ x^{j} \geq 13!\left(x^{2} + \color{red}{\binom{13}{8}^{-\frac 14}}\right)^{4}\tag1$$
The equality is attained when $x=0$ where
$\binom{13}{8}^{-1/4}=1287^{-1/4}\gt 1296^{-1/4}= \frac 16$.
We can also generalize the inequality $(1)$.
Let $$F_n(x):= \sum_{j = 0}^{8}\binom{8}{j}(j + n-8)!(8 -
j)!\ x^{j} -n!\left(x^{2} + \binom{n}{8}^{-\frac 14}\right)^{4}$$
Then, according to WolframAlpha, at least for $11\le n\le 30$, $F_n(x)\ge 0$ if and only if $x\ge 0$.
(It may be true that for all $n\ge 11$, $F_n(x)\ge 0$ if and only if $x\ge 0$.)

Added
Claim 1 :  For $n\ge 11$, $F_n(x)\ge 0$ holds for all $x\ge 0$.
Proof :
$F_n(x)\ge 0$ is equivalent to
$$xG_n(x)\ge 0$$
where
$$G_n(x)=b_6x^6-b_5x^5+b_4x^4-b_3x^3+b_2x^2-b_1x+b_0$$
$$\begin{align}b_6&=8 (n - 1)!
\\b_5&=\frac{4n!}{{\binom n8}^{1/4}}-56 (n - 2)!
\\b_4&=336 (n - 3)!
\\b_3&=\frac{6 n!}{\sqrt{\binom n8}}-1680 (n - 4)!
\\b_2&=6720 (n - 5)!
\\b_1&=\frac{4 n!}{{\binom n8}^{3/4}}-20160  (n - 6)!
\\b_0&=40320 (n - 7)!\end{align}$$
According to WolframAlpha, for $n\ge 203$, we have
$$\max\bigg(\frac{b_5}{b_6},\frac{b_3}{b_4},\frac{b_1}{b_2}\bigg)=\frac{b_5}{b_6},\min\bigg(\frac{b_4}{b_5},\frac{b_2}{b_3},\frac{b_0}{b_1}\bigg)=\frac{b_0}{b_1}$$
However, we have $\frac{b_5}{b_6}\gt \frac{b_0}{b_1}$ which means that my idea does not work for large $n$.
So, let us use your idea.
According to WolframAlpha, for $n\ge 12$, we have
$$2\sqrt{b_6\times\frac{b_4}{2}}-b_5\ge 0$$
$$2\sqrt{\frac{b_4}{2}\times\frac{b_2}{2}}-b_3\ge 0$$
$$2\sqrt{\frac{b_2}{2}\times b_0}-b_1\ge 0$$
So, we can say that for $n\ge 12$, $G_n(x)\ge 0$ holds for all $x\ge 0$.
WolframAlpha also says that for $n=11$, $F_n(x)\ge 0$ holds for all $x\ge 0$.
Therefore, the claim follows.$\ \blacksquare$

Nice! Does your method breaks for the general inequality that you stated above?

@STrick : I think yes. I added a claim with a proof using WolframAlpha.

@STrick : I'm not sure if I understand your comment correctly, but I think our sequence
$$(1,864,-408,8064,-12744,36288,-57024,114048)$$
is not log-concave since $(-408)^2<864\times 8064$.

Sorry, I would like to say log-convex. But in particular we would like to be log-convex only on some coordinates.
